# Where does the flink-conf.yaml go?

Tags: java, configuration, apache-flink, flink-streaming

The documentation on the flink website as well as AWS's Flink deployment says that my configuration goes in the flink-conf.yaml file but where should I store this file in my project and how do I get flink to pick it up?

In particular I want to enable checkpointing, how do I do that when my project tree is as follows:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── xyz
    │   │       └── foobar
    │   │           └── foo
    │   │               └── Main.java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── xyz
        │       └── foobar
        │           └── foo
        │               └── TestFoo.java
        └── resources
            └── placeholder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flink-conf.yaml` file lives in your Flink cluster, in the `conf` directory. It needs to be present in each job manager and task manager machine/container.

If you are using the official Docker images, this file goes into the `/opt/flink/conf` directory in the Flink image, as described [here in the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/docker/#provide-custom-configuration). For configuring a standalone Kubernetes cluster, see [Flink on Standalone Kubernetes Reference](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#configuration).

Comment: So should each worker node also have the flink-conf.yaml with updated config file or would the "master" propogate the configuration if I deploy from master?

Comment: Each worker node needs its own copy of the config file. They need parts of the config in order to launch.